# Para onde vão os ips do ip addr add?

Tags: linux

Olá galera tudo bem ? então sou novo com linux e queria saber para onde vão os ips que adicionamos pelo ip addr add x.x.x.x

Answer (score 1):

Esse comando define em tempo real um endereço na placa de rede especificada, por exemplo:

```
ip addr add 192.168.50.5 dev eth1
```

Essa configuração não é salva em nenhum arquivo: após a reinicialização do sistema, será perdida.